# SQL Server query to find the number of years enrolled by member

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have 2 tables:

Table `tbmembers`

```
id   name
----------
 1    abc
 2    def
 3    ghi
```

Table `tbmemberenrollment`

```
id    memberid(foreign key)   startyear    endyear
--------------------------------------------------
 1            1                2007       2009
 2            1                2011       2012
 3            1                2013       2017
```

In the `tbmemberenrollment` table I want to calculate the number of years for which the member is enrolled till the current year, in this case result would be 6 years(2007, 2008, 2009, 2011, 2012, 2013)

I want to calculate the above result by SQL query, I don't know how to use for loops in SQL Server or how can we use cursor to get the above result, please help.....

Comment: Are you really storing a year as an int?  Why aren't you storing a datetime?

Comment: no actually i am storing it as a date....then i am using year(date) to get the year, but if you can do it with int data type...then please tell me the solution

Comment: Could your data have 2007-2008 and then 2008-2009 (same start as end year)?  Counting those years you get 2007,2008,2008,2009 (4) vs the 3 distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your years might overlap (2007-2008 and then 2008-2009), the best option I see would be to create a Years lookup table and query against it, like such:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, COUNT(DISTINCT y.yearfield) YearCount
FROM tblmembers m 
  CROSS JOIN YearLookup Y 
  INNER JOIN tbmemberenrollment me 
    ON m.id = me.memberid 
      AND YEAR(y.yearfield) >= YEAR(me.startyear)
      AND YEAR(y.yearfield) <= YEAR(me.endyear)
AND YEAR(Y.yearField) <= YEAR(GetDate())
GROUP BY m.id, m.name
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2bb81/3)

If your data won't have these overlapped years, then you can do something like this to get the results:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, 
  SUM(
    CASE 
      WHEN YEAR(me.endyear) > YEAR(getDate()) 
      THEN YEAR(getDate()) 
      ELSE YEAR(me.endyear) 
    END - YEAR(me.startyear) + 1
    ) totYears
FROM tblmembers m 
  LEFT JOIN tbmemberenrollment me on m.id = me.memberid
WHERE YEAR(me.startyear) <= YEAR(getDate())
GROUP BY  m.id, m.name
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/15d6a/1)

*EDIT: Using a recursive CTE vs. a Lookup table*

While I would still recommend using the lookup table, sometimes that is not a viable option.  In those cases, you can accomplish the same thing using a recursive CTE.

```
WITH years AS (
  SELECT MAX(endyear) maxyear, MIN(startyear) minyear 
  FROM tbmemberenrollment
  ),
RecursiveCTE AS (
  SELECT minyear yearfield
  FROM years
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(year, 1, yearfield)
  FROM RecursiveCTE R 
    JOIN years T
      ON R.yearfield < T.maxyear
  )
SELECT m.id, m.name, COUNT(DISTINCT y.yearfield) YearCount
FROM tblmembers m 
  CROSS JOIN RecursiveCTE Y 
  INNER JOIN tbmemberenrollment me 
    ON m.id = me.memberid 
      AND YEAR(y.yearfield) >= YEAR(me.startyear)
      AND YEAR(y.yearfield) <= YEAR(me.endyear)
AND YEAR(Y.yearField) <= YEAR(GetDate())
GROUP BY m.id, m.name
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply sgeddes, but how can i save the distinct year values in yearlookup temporary table

Comment: @bhanu -- while I would recommend creating the lookup table (for performance issues mainly), if you can't, you can accomplish the same thing using a recursive CTE.  Here is an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/15d6a/2 -- Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

How about?:

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT c.yr) 
FROM   (SELECT a.startyear AS yr 
        FROM   tbmemberenrollment a 
        UNION 
        SELECT b.endyear AS yr 
        FROM   tbmemberenrollment b) AS c
```

Comment: I assume that using a cursor in a "for loop" is not a requirement of the answer. I recommend, almost always, to avoid loops in SQL...

Answer (score 0):

This is a good condidate for CTE query.

```
;with memberEnrollment_CTE(memberid, Eyear, Startyear, Endyear)
as
(
  SELECT memberid, startyear as EYear, startyear, endyear
  from dbo.tbmemberenrollment
  union all
  select memberid, Eyear+1, Startyear, Endyear
  from memberEnrollment_CTE
  where endyear>yyear
)
select distinct memberid, Eyear as EnrolledYear from memberEnrollment_CTE where     
 Eyear<=     YEAR(GETDATE())
```

This even works for overlap enrolled years. And should give you all the years, so you can run count() queries over this or join with member table.

Answer (score 0):

If your years do *not* overlap, you can do an aggregation:

```
select tm.name,
       sum(case when endyear <= year(getdate()) then endyear - startyear + 1
                else year(getdate()) - startyear + 1
           end) as EnrollmentYears
from tmembers tm join
     tbmemberenrollment tme
     on tm.id = tme.memberid
where startyear <= year(getdate())
```